# What is the difference between Debian slim-buster and buster images?

Tags: debian, docker, java

I can't any documentation stating what is the difference between `Debian Buster` and `Debian Slim Buster`.
I am reffering to these images: https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/8u252-jre-slim-buster/images/sha256-01dfdeac537b9d9adcb2399028fba063733a77186c5264e6b059987002c0e48c?context=explore

and

https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/8u252-jre-buster/images/sha256-ed067a5ac4a985b470c6c1ec711087d1c52c8ba8acd32bb90be2c93dfce4ceae?context=explore

There is 40MB size difference, but I can't ANY documentation what is difference between these two distributions. I can only guess that there are some UI features cut, but guessing is not enough.

**Question:** What is the difference between slim-buster and buster?

Answer (score 2):

Based on a visual comparison of the filesystems, -slim excludes:

- /usr/share/locale (so you can't switch the OS to languages other than US English)
- /usr/share/doc and /usr/share/man (so there's no local documentation)